# How to limit total memory consumed by Java 8 application?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, java-8

In order to limit total memory consumed by Java 7 application I could use the following formula (taken from [this article](https://plumbr.eu/blog/why-does-my-java-process-consume-more-memory-than-xmx)):

> Max memory = [-Xmx] + [-XX:MaxPermSize] + number_of_threads * [-Xss]

How this formula changes for Java 8 application, after PermGen has been removed?

Should I use option "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize" to limit the maximum memory consumed by metaspace instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` instead of `-XX:MaxPermSize`.

Consider also `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` to limit memory for direct ByteBuffers.